# How to use multiple liquibase migration changelog files in dropwizard 1.3.x?

Tags: java, sql, liquibase

Here is what I'm looking at:

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html (This is to use the includeAll tag)

https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/migrations.html (This is for configuring Liquibase in my current dropwizard version)

Note on the 2nd link, it specifically states "Your database migrations are stored in your Dropwizard project, in src/main/resources/migrations.xml".

My migrations.xml file is very huge now, and I'd like to start new changesets in a new file. Let's call this "migrations2.xml".

My current structure is

`--src
   -- main
     -- resources
       -- migrations.xml`

I changed it to 

`--src
  -- main
    -- resources 
      -- changelogs
        -- migrations.xml
        -- migrations2.xml`

And now migrations.xml contains `<includeAll path="src/main/resources/changelogs/"/>`

Now I run into an issue when running migration task with `liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: migrations.xml does not exist`

According to the dropwizard docs, it makes sense because it's no longer under "src/main/resources". Instead it's in "src/main/resources/changelogs". How can I fix this to make sure it's not a weird structure where I have to keep the main migration xml file containing the `includeAll` tag outisde of the `changelogs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be a good idea to make the following structure:

```
--src
   -- main
     -- resources
       -- changelogs
          -- migrations1.xml
          -- migrations2.xml
          -- ...
          -- migrationsN.xml
       -- migrations.xml (it's a master changeLog which includes all the other changeLogs)
```

Try setting relative path to your child changeLog files as such:

`<includeAll path="/changelogs" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>`

In the first link on `includeAll` docs there's a part about why it's not a very good practice to use it

> While the includeAll tag has many valuable uses, its use can cause
>   problems down the road. The biggest thing to avoid is to use the
>   includeAll tag to simulate Ruby on Rails Active Migrations strategy of
>   a list of changes, one per file, that are ran in file order. While
>   this seems like a good idea at first, it quickly runs into problems
>
> If
>   you do choose to use the includeAll tag, make sure you have a naming
>   strategy in place that will insure that you will never have conflicts
>   or need to rename files to change to force a reordering.

so perhaps you may consider using `<include>` tag and list all the child changeLog files.

E.G.:

```
<include path="changelogs/migrations1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include path="changelogs/migrations2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
...etc.
```

Comment: is relativeToChangelogFile needed? It seems to work fine without it

Comment: Well, it’s up to you. If it works without it, then use what suites you better. This attribute is not mandatory